# Why was the question about Mom having a chicken farm closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

I was looking through some questions and saw that this question [Did Mom have a chicken farm?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20013/did-mom-have-a-chicken-farm) was closed as "Not constructive".  I don't personally see how this question could "solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" so I was just wondering why exactly this was closed?

It seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.  I'm not sure if there is an in universe answer to the question but is that really a reason to close a question instead of posting an answer of "there is no in universe information about this".  Even if there is no in universe explanation it does seem entirely possible that maybe on some commentary somebody mentioned something.

However, that might not be related to why it was closed at all so I was just looking for some insight into why this was closed.

Comment: And closed without a single comment at that. I don't think any question (at least non-absurd ones) should be closed, especially by 5 votes, without a comment.

Comment: People tend to be quick to follow one vote with the remaining 4.

Comment: It may have to do with asking for an in-universe explanation of a plot detail in a work that is known for its absurdist leanings, not for its plot consistency.

Comment: @Gilles - that's still no excuse for closing without explanation (as seems to be a bad habit on SFF). Frankly, I can easily see myself asking such a question since my effective knowledge of Futurama is close to zero so I have no clue about its property of "known for its absurdist leanings, not for its plot consistency". Well, I can see myself asking such a question if I didn't ignore Futurama as a tag, at least :)

Comment: I definitely agree with DVK here.  When Gilles posted that my initial reaction was "so you're telling me it was closed specifically because it was a Futurama question?" and to be honest that just doesn't seem right especially since there weren't any comments left.  I held off because if I recall correctly Gilles wasn't one who voted to close so they were just giving a guess as to why it was closed.  It still doesn't seem right to me though.  I'm not saying there is a decent answer to the question but I don't really like how it was handled.

Comment: I think sometimes a question is simply too strange or absurd (particularly given Futurama's basic premise) to warrant even questioning. Did Mom feed chickens to the Nibblonians? Yes. Is Mom one of the richest people on Earth? Yes. Is it too hard to believe she may have had the ability to buy a chicken farm, at least for a time? No. Why are we answering that question, again?

Answer (score 5):

More than 3 years later, but...

I just cast the final vote to **undelete this question**, bringing it back into the public eye. For good measure I also **voted to reopen**, just to get it onto the review queue so that people are aware of it.

Comment: *sigh*. I was SOOOO hoping that the Trauma of Futurama was fully behind us :(

Comment: @DVK Um, was there a lot of controversy over this question or over Futurama questions in general? I'm too much of a noob to know these historical things ...

Comment: you're **lucky** :) http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=futurama+is%3Aquestion . Basically, we got overflooded with Futurama questions, many of questionable quality, as part of a promotional event

Comment: that was back when I actually was motivated to help improve the site... :)

Answer (score 2):

This question is moot at the moment, as the OP deleted it. I rarely will undelete something the OP deleted. Still, it does seem to me like it was closed unjustly... It is a bit absurd, but then again, Futurama seems to be completely absurd, so...

Comment: Is it possible to ping the user in chat and ask them if they'd be OK with undeleting + un-closing? or do they have to be an active chat user for that? This way you have their consent. +1 for showing an extra consideration of users' wishes.